Handling Long-Running Tasks and Subtasks with RabbitMQ and AWS Batch
Question:
I'm working on a system where I have a producer that initiates multiple tasks, each of which can take a significant amount of time to complete. Here's an overview of the system architecture:

The producer first calls Task-A, which initiates a long-running process that can take anywhere from 20 minutes to several hours to complete. Once Task-A is completed, it triggers several subtasks, each represented by a separate topic exchange (e.g., A-findB, A-findC, A-findE).
Here is a sample code of Task-A.

const OrbitSubs = require("./Batchs/OrbitSubs");

const recive = async () => {
  let conn = await amqp.connect("amqp://localhost");
  let channel = await conn.createChannel();

  var queue = "runSubs";

  channel.assertQueue(queue, {
    durable: true,
  });

  channel.consume(
    queue,
    async function (msg) {
      try {
        let jsonObj = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());
        let { domain, id } = jsonObj;
        let status = await OrbitSubs(domain, id);

        // Send acknowledgment only after job processing is complete
        channel.ack(msg);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error processing message:", error);
       
        channel.reject(msg, false); // Requeue the message
      }
    },
    {
      noAck: false, // Use manual acknowledgment
    }
  );
};

recive();

       +--------------------------------+
       |           Producer             |
       +--------------------------------+
                    |
                    | Calls Task-A
                    |
       +--------------------------------+
       |          RabbitMQ              |
       +--------------------------------+
                    |
                    | Publishes Task-A to Queue
                    |
       +--------------------------------+
       |         AWS Batch               |
       +--------------------------------+
                    |
                    | Executes Task-A
                    |
       +--------------------------------+
       |          RabbitMQ              |
       +--------------------------------+
                    |
                    | Publishes Subtasks (e.g., A-findB, A-findC, A-findE)
                    |
       +--------------------------------+
       |         AWS Batch               |
       +--------------------------------+
                    |
                    | Executes Subtasks
                    |
       +--------------------------------+
       |          RabbitMQ              |
       +--------------------------------+
                    |
                    | Publishes Subtask Results (e.g., A-findB1, A-findC1, A-findE1)
                    |
       +--------------------------------+
       |         Consumer               |
       +--------------------------------+
                    |
                    | Receives Subtask Results
                    |
       +--------------------------------+


The main challenges I'm facing are:
a) Maintaining Connection: As Task-A can take a long time to complete, I'm losing connection with RabbitMQ before it finishes. I'm currently checking the state of AWS Batch tasks every 5 seconds, but I need to keep my connection alive throughout the entire process. How can I ensure that my connection remains active, even during long-running tasks that can last for hours?
b) Handling Subtasks: Once Task-A is completed, I need to handle the subtasks (e.g., A-findB1, A-findC1, A-findE1) sequentially. Is it possible to receive multiple acknowledgments from a single producer, or should I send each subtask to the queue separately after Task-A completes?

Alternate Approaches: If my approach to handling subtasks isn't optimal, I'm open to alternative ideas. How can I efficiently manage long-running tasks and their associated subtasks in RabbitMQ and AWS Batch?


I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address these challenges and improve the efficiency and reliability of my system architecture. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Edit
A sample visual on task
    Task-A
             / | \
            /  |  \
           /   |   \
    Subtask-B Subtask-C Subtask-E
       / | \      |         |
      /  |  \     |         |
     /   |   \    |         |
  Sub-B1 Sub-B2 Sub-B3    Sub-E1
   /  \    / \  
  /    \  /   \
Sub-B1-1 Sub-B1-2 Sub-B2-1 Sub-B2-2
   |        |       |       |
   |        |       |       |
Sub-B1-1-1 Sub-B1-1-2 Sub-B2-1-1 Sub-B2-1-2
                      |
                      |
                   Sub-C1
                      |
                      |
                   Sub-C1-1


+1 to not implementing your own workflow orchestration system. Take your pick from tons out there including AWS Step Functions, BullMQ, etc. They can all work with Batch to execute the jobs.  What do you populate the RabbitMQ from?

Don't use a queue. Your use case is trivially implemented as an orchestration using a system like temporal.io. It supports long running tasks out of the box.
